# Using SVN and Maven in Eclipse for rapid development

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I'm developing using Eclipse with SVN and Maven (flat structure).

I have my SVN repository set up to use trunk/branches/tags.

My Eclipse project structure is:
  core - Common java utilities that might be used in multiple projects
  projectX - A Java project (depends on core-utilities)
  projectX-maven - A Maven "pom" project used only for building all related Maven modules

projectX-maven has a "pom.xml that simply includes core and projectX as dependency modules.

What I want to do is be able to quickly switch between my branch and trunk when I need to make a quick fix to the trunk code (without having my branch changes included).

I thought I could just use "Team-Switch to another Branch/Tag/Version" to go between my branch and trunk and then fire off my projectX-maven.

However, it seems that "switching" only changes the repository location, not the code.

I have read lots of people suggesting having multiple Eclipse project sets (one for branch and one for trunk).

I'm wondering if there a way to do this without having 2 sets of projects (core-branch, core-trunk, projectX-branch, projectX-trunk, projectX-maven-branch, projectX-maven-trunk)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to work a lot with branches I would definitely recommend investing time learning and using `git` for your version control. It is much more flexible and much faster than svn.